# Change in math site display on Mobile

Tags: support, mobile-web

For a week or so, the display of the math site has changed on my mobile. Much less userfriendly. 
This is not the case for other sites, such as this meta. Do we know why? Could it be reverseo on a phomene? For references see screenshots for meta and math sites. 
[image: math site]

[image: meta sitee]

Comment: Can you maybe give screenshots that contain actual details? These are far too small to be of any use...

Comment: "reverseo on a phomene"??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like it is the "full site" displayed on a small screen.

Just scroll to the end. After the question-list, there you will find the usual footer including the option to select "mobile."

It is part of a list with heading "Mathematics" that goes like this:

- Tour
- Help
- Chat
- Contact
- Feedback
- **Mobile**
- Disable Responsiveness

Selecting "mobile" will bring back the layout you have on meta.

At the moment, I am not sure if the reason this changed for you is something that SE did or if you switched it (by accident) earlier. (In the mobile view you can do the same thing and then select "full site.")

Comment: Perfect thanks!!